# How can I SELECT rows by using xpath on an XML column?

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xpath

I have a table with a column named `Description` that contains XML like:

```
<Parent>
  <Child Target="A" Id="123456">
       <SpecialCode Target="I"  Value="2530138" />
  </Child>
</Parent>
```

If I want to set a parameter called `@value` that represents the Value attribute in this xml,

How can I `SELECT` the rows from `MyTable` where the `Description` column has a `SpecialCode` attribute that is equal to `@value` ?

```
DECLARE @value varchar(20);
SET @value = '44555'
SELECT ....
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT (list of columns)
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE [Description].exist('/Parent/Child/SpecialCode[@Value=sql:variable("@value")]') = 1
```

If your XML column is in a different column, then you'll use :

```
SELECT (list of columns)
FROM dbo.MyTable t1
INNER JOIN dbo.MyTable t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t2.[Description].exist('/Parent/Child/SpecialCode[@Value=sql:variable("@value")]') = 1
```

Just alias your tables, properly join them, and prepend your XML column with the appropriate table alias....

Comment: Great! Thanks! What if it is a column coming from another table that I joined?